# Один экземпляр программы

Tags: c#, sql-server

Допустим, есть некоторая программа, которая что то делает с базой. Пользователи могут запускать ее на разных машинах. Можно ли сделать так, что бы не смотря на то, что программы работают на разных машинах, что бы несмотря на это могла работать только 1 программа. Была мысль эксклюзивно блокировать таблицы, но может быть ещё решения? Запускаются программы от 1 учетки. Может быть программа, как то может идентифицировать своё соединение например названием программы, а другой экземпляр мог бы проверить не ют ли уже соединений?

Comment: Советую не выдумывать свое собственное лицензирование, а использовать существующие решения.

Comment: Не, это не совсем лицензирование. Параллельный запуск может все попортить.

Comment: Тогда возможно стоит посмотреть на то, почему именно параллельный запуск может что либо испортить. И работать с данными таким образом, что бы не портило (например как раз используя блокировки, но например не целых таблиц а конкретных данных с которыми идет работа)

Comment: Мне нравится идея с блокировкой.

Answer (score 1):

Да, название программы можно передать через соединение

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AWConnection"].ToString();

SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connStr);
sb.ApplicationName = "MySuperApp";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sb.ToString());
//ну и далее...
```

А потом уже в SQL Server можно сделать запрос к `sys.dm_exec_session` и в столбце `program_name` обнаружить название нашей проги, а столбце `login_time` время начала сессии.

Comment: А надежно ли это использовать? Есть вероятность, что программы параллельно запустится черкнут сессии и увидят только себя и продолжат работать?

Comment: Да, такая ситуация вполне возможна. Как вариант с помощью триггера [ограничить количество соединений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510907/limit-all-users-to-1-session).

Answer (score 0):

Пусть программа каждые скажем 5 сек отправляет в базу какие нибудь данные с уникальным ключем, и при присутствии этих данных другие клиенты не смогут работать.